# How to inject a script on the page after I click the miniplayer button on Youtube

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, youtube, pushstate

I am making a chrome extension and I was wonder how to show a youtube search result page after I minimized the video I was watching. My intention

content.js

```
    ...
    $('input#search').attr("value", someVarValue);
    $('.ytp-miniplayer-button').trigger('click');
    $('button#search-icon-legacy').trigger('click');
    ...
```

The first two works fine but when the third one initiated it closes the miniplayer and straight went to result page, I want to show the searched result page without closing the miniplayer video I was watching. I try to use replacestate but it will only go to the result page when I use forward/backward. 
Any advice or general approach would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you add any details like error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just rewrite the question. Its related to youtube and javascript.